# Billing in CosmosDb when increasing RU for 5 minutes

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

How would billing work in Azure CosmosDb if I use the SDK to increase the throughput for a small amount of time, like 5 minutes?

Will I be charged one hour of the max RU or just a fraction of the hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed CosmosDB charges you for the highest provisioned throughput within an hour. It is also cycle based so if you increase at 01:58 and decrease at 02:03 (o'clock might not be the actual cycle time) you could be charged for 2 hours.

- Reserved RUs/second (per 100 RUs, 400 RUs minimum)    £0.006/hour

"You're billed the flat rate for each hour the container or database exists, regardless of usage or if the container or database is active for less than an hour. For example, if you create a container or database and delete it 5 minutes later, your bill will reflect a 1 hour."

More info here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/